# GPU coherence and power consumption: does it save power to run code only on one thread per warp?

Tags: cuda, gpu, vulkan, gpgpu, compute-shader

In GPU programming, one cares a lot about "coherence": threads are executed in so called "warps" (each roughly 32 threads large). All threads of a warp run in "lockstep" so that the same instruction is always executed for all of them. If there is a branch that only part of those threads take, the other threads are disabled, but don't do anything useful in the meantime. This is called divergence. The opposite (all threads always executing useful instructions together) is called coherence.

My question is about what exactly disabled threads do. And in particular: do disabled threads consume the same power as enabled ones?

Many GPU architectures use thread masking, where a flag per thread stores whether the thread is "actually" executing that instruction. I heard newer GPU architectures have one program counter per thread, which is a bit better in some regards. If disabled threads still completely execute all instructions, but results are simply never flushed due to the thread mask, then I assume the power consumption is also the same.

---

To make it a bit more concrete, assume I have a compute shader with 16x16 workgroup size. I need to calculate some value that's the same for all threads in the workgroup. Calculation is hard to parallelize (and doesn't take too long), so I just write it in normal serial fashion.

In that situation, is there any benefit to wrap an `if (gl_LocalInvocationIndex == 0)` around that code and write the results to workgroup shared memory? Or can I just have all threads execute the code?

Comment: "*I heard newer GPU architectures have one program counter per thread*" Citation needed. If a GPU has a separate program counter for each thread, then those threads can execute different instructions. And thus, what you call "coherence" does not exist for those architectures. That is, there are no "warps"; just threads. Perhaps you misunderstood what "thread" meant in the context you read this in.

Comment: @NicolBolas Apparently this was introduced by Nvidias Volta architecture and is called "Independent Thread Scheduling". For example. from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html): "Starting with the NVIDIA Volta architecture, Independent Thread Scheduling allows full concurrency between threads, regardless of warp. With Independent Thread Scheduling, the GPU maintains execution state per thread, including a program counter and call stack".

Comment: Note, this question likely counts as opinion based, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323354/5899776. Threads on GPUs aren't the same as those on CPUs; they could be better described as execution states, the actual execution is done on SIMT cores. Threads having their own PC is about improving branching (masking is a pain; try keeping track of deep branches), but the warp still runs best when all instructions are in lockstep. The 3rd paragraph of §4.1 makes it pretty clear that the GPU still disables threads not running the current instruction, and works towards reconverging the branches.

Comment: @vandench I don't understand how this could be interpreted as opinion based. Either modern GPUs save power or they don't. It's a fact. That's ideally answered with a good source. I also fail to see the connection to the meta question you posted. Your remaining comment is unfortunately pretty orthogonal to my question and I have no idea what dokument you refer to with "3rd paragraph".

Comment: It's opinion based because the answers you're looking for require an understanding of the underlying architecture, something which is proprietary and private. You also can't simply check the power draw of the GPU, there is so much that happens inside that correlating the tiny changes in power draw to a single WARP is near impossible. We can only make educated guesses as to what actually happens, but it's near impossible to find an authoritative source. I was referencing https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html, which you referenced in your prior comment.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it save power to run code only on one thread per warp?

It doesn't matter, since if you do that, you're wasting your GPU. Might as well just run your code on the CPU if you plan on using one thread per warp, it'll waste less power and be faster to boot.

... but to be less facetious:

> what exactly [do] disabled threads do... do disabled threads consume the same power as enabled ones?

There are no such threads. It's just a metaphor. Think of a GPU warp as a 32-lane-wide SIMD register on the CPU. (Not that GPU hardware is exactly like that necessarily.)

Now, the easiest way to implement "thread disabling" is to just have mask bits for each thread in a warp, and use it to disable writing a result and perhaps to avoid divide-by-zero exceptions and the like. I very much doubt the useless computation would be avoided in order to save power - although it is possible theoretically.

You could check, I suppose: Write two kernels, all doing the same kind of computation (try to make it intensive if you can, so perhaps interleave different kinds of operations so that different warps keep each core busy), and arrange it so that one of them makes 31 of the 32 warp "threads" disabled (e.g. `if (threadIdx.x % 32 == 0) { /* do work */ }` ). Make them run for a long enough time for the power consumption to stabilize, and measure that consumption, e.g. using `nvidia-smi`.